Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 - wordpress setup error
Current my webpage is looking like below, after cloning a wordpress project and access through localhost:

As you cans ee CSS file is not loading: e.g /var/www/html/dipkar-wp/wp-content/themes/dipkar/assets/css/style.min.css
There is the following error in Inspection Mode forstyle.min.css:
GET http://localhost/dipkar-wp/wp-content/themes/dipkar/assets/css/style.min.css?ver=6.6.1 404 (Not Found)

All of the links will also break if clicked.
I setup the website at /var/www/html/dipkar-wp I am setting up on a Ubuntu 22.04 laptop.
Files/Folders in  /var/www/html/dipkar-wp are:
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   405 Thg 8  18 15:52 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Thg 8  18 15:52 srt2text
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  7387 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data  4096 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-admin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   351 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-blog-header.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  2323 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-comments-post.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  3040 Thg 9   2 10:01 wp-config.php
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data  4096 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-content
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  5638 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 30 www-data www-data 12288 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-includes
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  2502 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-links-opml.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  3937 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-load.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data 51238 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-login.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  8525 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-mail.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data 28774 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-settings.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data 34385 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-signup.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  4885 Thg 8  18 15:52 wp-trackback.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  3246 Thg 8  18 15:52 xmlrpc.php

Content of /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dipkar-wp
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    <Directory /var/www/html/dipkar-wp>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /wp-content /var/www/html/dipkar-wp/wp-content
    <Directory /var/www/html/dipkar-wp/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

I can only think that I didn't setup url in my project properly. However, I don't know what the specific setting problem might be.
Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Check if the file /var/www/html/dipkar-wp/wp-content/themes/dipkar/assets/css/style.min.css exists.
Note the missing file name is style.min.css, not style.css.

Yes, the file exists at this location /var/www/html/dipkar-wp/wp-content/themes/dipkar/assets/css/style.min.css
